# Breaking apart a WPF/XAML project while under development

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I hope this is not an obscure question.  I expect there are several ways people accomplish it and the approach I'm using seems excessively labor-intensive.

How do I break apart a presentation-layer project (XAML/WPF) into several temporary "side-by-side" projects so that I can make enhancements efficiently in VS 2015 and unit-test them quickly?  The end result being that, once the unit tests are successful, I combine the projects back as they were again (with a focus on organization rather than developer efficiency).

The problem for me is *not* one of analyzing the inter-dependencies, *not* one of identifying project boundaries, and *not* one of adding the newly created (temporary) project references where needed.  The *biggest* problem I have is with all the silly XAML namespace references (clr-namespace:). They need updating so they will point to the new home assemblies (assembly=) for the referenced resources.  This is a *ton* of overhead and doesn't always have a pay-off since it is temporary work in the first place.  Where is the tool to do this for me?  And revert it back out afterwards so that I don't accidentally promote temporary XAML changes into source control?

I thought about managing an entirely separate set of sln's and csproj's for WIP development but this is impossible for the same underlying reason based on the way those XAML namespace references (clr-namespace:) work.  Also it is hard to do it as a team effort.

More info:

The reason I ask is because we have a number of projects with XAML resources (user controls, resource dictionaries, etc).  Some of these get quite large because they are organized in a certain way that makes them a common place to put stuff (ie. all the combobox lookup - ALT-down - windows, or all common data templates, or what-not).  Over time it becomes a problem because VS build operations take too long (impacts development efficiency).  VS build operations get slower for larger projects:

- a project with a centralized list of all data templates is likely to have a lot of things above it in the dependency stack, causing *numerous* other projects to be rebuilt after every change
- any project with a central repository of anything will grow large and take a long time to compile (5 seconds /project is about my limit while I'm actively developing XAML, with a cap at 10 seconds to do the entire build operation and start debugging)

Comment: what do you want to unit test? the controls themselves, or their viewmodels? are you using MVVM?

Comment: why dont you just split the project into usercontrol libraries permanently?

Comment: 1 - Get an SSD. 2 - Get an SSD. 3 - use `[assembly:XmlnsDefinition("MyXamlNamespace")]`

Comment: No, the bottleneck is definitely CPU and not my disk (I do use SSD).  XAML *view* projects don't need to get very big before hitting a 5 CPU-second cap.   It doesn't help that VS always runs csc.exe on them *twice*.  Thanks for the tip on XmlnsDefinition.  That sounds like it might do the trick.  I'll google for it.

Comment: The XmlsDefinition almost does the trick, and I guess I'd give credit to whoever writes it as an answer and can avoid the issue whereby it can't actually be used for references within the local assembly.  In other words, I can split an assembly apart and use the xaml namespace temporarily for some of my references (instead of a clr-namespace). But when I combine things back together I'm forced to go back to clr-namespaces.  This means editing namespace references before and after the projects are split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > The biggest problem I have is with all the silly XAML namespace
   >   references (clr-namespace:). They need updating so they will point to
   >   the new home assemblies (assembly=)

   Generally, ReSharper does great job, when refactorig xaml. It analyzes xaml files, and fixes wrong xml namespaces. However, you would need to go trough all the files, one by one.

   You can also use just plain Find/Replace dialog and replace `;assemmly=TempProject` with empty string. Write powershell script for that, if you need to do it more often.
2. > And revert it back out afterwards so that I don't accidentally promote
   >   temporary XAML changes into source control?

   You just need to be carefull when doing check-ins, compare files with they original version and investigate changes

However, there is only one good solution for you. Split the projects into wpf usercontrol libraries. Not just for testing purposes, but permanently. Try to break your large resource files. Don't use practices like `common place to put stuff` when working on large projects. Consider using loosely coupled design and IoC (assembly injection instead of direct references) when possible. Create this shared assembly, which all other assemblies will reference. Don't create component that references lot of other components, but let the others inject themselves instead. Take a look at prism for an insipration: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/prism-introduction

Comment: I am a huge fan of loosely coupled design and IoC.  However, these don't preclude the need for well-organized assemblies that may get large over time.  Eg. If I have a third-party assembly called "MyThirdParty.ChartingControls" that is over 3 MB in size, it is because it likely contains all their charting controls.  But while they distribute it in this monstrous size, I can't imagine the developers are constantly recompiling 3 MB every time they tweak a control.  I expect they work with smaller-sized temporary projects and combine them during production releases. No?

Comment: Maybe there are tools to merge multiple assemblies into one, but the starting point is to have standalone assemblies.

Comment: OK, I'm convinced that it is easier to merge than to split.  But I'm not getting the sympathy I was expecting for my temporary project-splitting requirements.  What if I'm a junior programmer who cannot permanently reorganize the project but I need to work for a couple days on a few of the controls in there.  Why can't I just avoid the 10-or-20-second compile time for that project by splitting out these controls temporarily?  Is it so difficult to relate to this?  It is just a basic need-for-speed when I F5 and start debugging.....